# sort eigen vectorXf in ascending order

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to sort an `Eigen` `VectorXf` `x` in ascending order.

This sorts it in descending order:

```
std::sort(x.data(),x.data()+x.size());
```

and this doesn't work:

```
bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }
std::sort(x.data(),x.data()+x.size(),myfunction);
```

any ideas?

Comment: Try lambda? ;-) `x.data()+x.size(), [](int a, int b){return a > b})`... Or just send in `std::greater<int>()`. Or `reverse` after sorting. Or...

Comment: Okay, I'll write it up as an answer so it can be answered.

Comment: Your original method sort it as ascending order actually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Preface** 
Since the original question turned out to be a misunderstanding, and the code in it is already the proper answer, I decided to write up and post a bit about using `std::sort` in general.

`std::sort` sorts range in ascending order defined by weak ordering of the elements. By default it uses `<` operator defined on elements, but it can also take a function object or functor to provide the comparison. This functor needs to have properly overloaded function with signature of `bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const`. An example of this follows:

```
struct FooSorter {
    bool operator (const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) const {
        return lhs.ham_index < rhs.ham_index;
    }
};
/* ... */
std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec), FooSorter());
```

This would sort the full range represented by vec, according to criteria defined in `FooSorter`'s `operator()`.

Because writing custom functors for the simple things (sort in descending order, sort in ascending order) would quickly grow painful,  STL provides many templated functors ready to use in [functional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) header. The one relevant for sorting are:

- `std::equal_to` implementing x == y
- `std::not_equal_to` implementing x != y
- `std::greater` implementing x > y
- `std::less` implementing x < y
- `std::greater_equal` implementing x >= y
- `std::less_equal` implementing x <= y

All of these are templated and can be used for any type, that implements needed operators. Using these is easy:

```
std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec), std::greater<int>());
```

This would sort the range represented by vector in descending order.

But, since one of the biggest problems of STL algorithms was the pain of defining functors, C++11 brings a new trick: [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). This lets you declare function object equivalent inline. Example follows:

```
std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec), [](int lhs, int rhs){return rhs > lhs});
```

This would also sort the range represented by vector in descending order, but we didn't have to explicitly declare a functor (or use already declared one). (This gets much better when implementing much more complex comparisons, or functors for different STL algorithms.)

Comment: @user189035 And what error are you getting? What type are the members inside vector? Give me more information.

Comment: actually the correct answer is just std::sort(x.data(),x.data()+x.size()). I knew this before but hadn't used cpp in a while and forgot. It came back in the train. Anyway, if you change your answer, I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: @user189035 Aaaaaand this why one needs to read the questions carefully. :-D (Since you wrote that the usual invocation sorts your vector the wrong way round, I just wrote an answer as to how you can sort them the other way around, instead of how to sort them ascendingly.) I'll update the answer in a bit to elaborate more on `std::sort`, functors and such, to provide some value.

Comment: @user189035 Okay, now it should be a bit better ;-)

Comment: thank you very much! Sorry for the original misunderstanding~but you managed to turn things around and made the internet a better place for it!

Comment: @user189035 `std::sort(x.data(), x.data() + x.size())` breaks if the stride of the vector is not 1 i.e. non-consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for an answer, here how I did it. In this way, you can get eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors as well. Here **covariance_matrix** is the matrix in which eigenvalues and eigenvectors are to be solved.

```
    std::vector<std::tuple<float, Eigen::VectorXf>> eigen_vectors_and_values; 

    Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> eigensolver(covariance_matrix);
    if (eigensolver.info() != Eigen::Success) {
        return;
    }
    Eigen::VectorXf eigen_values = eigensolver.eigenvalues();
    Eigen::MatrixXf eigen_vectors = eigensolver.eigenvectors();
    for(int i=0; i<eigen_values.size(); i++){
        std::tuple<float, Eigen::VectorXf> vec_and_val(eigen_values[i], eigen_vectors.row(i));
        eigen_vectors_and_values.push_back(vec_and_val);
    }
    std::sort(eigen_vectors_and_values.begin(), eigen_vectors_and_values.end(), 
        [&](const std::tuple<float, Eigen::VectorXf>& a, const std::tuple<float, Eigen::VectorXf>& b) -> bool{ 
            return std::get<0>(a) < std::get<0>(b); 
    });
```

Note: Be careful when selecting which eigensolver is to be used. You may find here which one to be used: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Eigenvalues__Module.html

Comment: Thanks, but it the first time I found an answer of another question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686548/sorting-eigenvectors-by-their-eigenvalues-associated-sorting) on a different page. Should you delete and move your answer to the other page ?

Comment: also it should be `eigen_vectors.col(i)` instead of `eigen_vectors.row(i)` because eigen vectors are returned in a vector column.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this complete answer for sorting both, eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Is it correct to return row() in

```
std::tuple<float, Eigen::VectorXf> vec_and_val(eigen_values[i], eigen_vectors.row(i));
```

From what is stated in the [documentation of Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html#a114189009e42f5e03372a7a3dfa33b97), it should be col()